# Delete duplicate records in the final output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I am using below query to output results. This is just a sample for one account.
For this account abc, I am seeing duplicate records in my output. See below.
Record only needs to be deleted if values are duplicate in all the columns. If there are more than 2 duplicates, I just want to keep the first unique record and delete the rest.

Can someone please help modify this code to get the desired output.

```
SELECT
    T.AccountId
    , CASE WHEN T.Status in (3,4,5,6) then -Amount else Amount end as Payment_Amount
    , DATEADD(hh,11,T.CreatedTimestamp) AS PaymentDate
    , CASE WHEN T.[ReferenceNumber] LIKE '%card%' THEN 'Card'
      WHEN T.[ReferenceNumber] LIKE '%bank%' THEN 'Bank'
      ELSE 'BPay'
      END AS PaymentType
    , CASE
      WHEN T.Status = 2 THEN 'Captured'
      WHEN T.Status = 5 THEN 'Refunded'
      WHEN T.Status = 6 THEN 'Dishonoured'
      ELSE 'Unknown'
      END AS [Status]
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.* ,
        ps.status,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ps.paymentid ORDER BY ps.createdtimestamp DESC) AS rno
    FROM table1 p
    INNER JOIN table2 ps on p.id = ps.PaymentId
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            a.id AS accountid,
            th.id,
            th.TimeStamp
        FROM table3 a
        INNER JOIN table4 th on a.Id=th.AccountId and th.Type=39
    ) w 
    on p.AccountId=w.accountId and p.CreatedTimestamp>=w.timestamp
    WHERE
        DATEADD(hh,11,P.CreatedTimestamp) >= @startDate and DATEADD(hh,11,P.CreatedTimestamp) < @endDate
) T
WHERE accountid = abc
and Status in (2,5,6)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a minimal question and query.

Comment: I have added the query I am using. I just want the final output to have no duplicates.

Comment: Please don't use images for data... use formatted text. And when Tim says minimal, he means exactly not your full query, but as small a query as you can come up with which shows a similar issue. You real query is too complex for anyone to consider.

Comment: You don't have enough information in your results to decide which rows to keep. You are almost there with your (unused) row number, you obviously need the most recent row of each group of rows, but what defines each group, youe logic is not clear without a description since the bottom two rows are not duplicates according to PaymentType.

Comment: You have obfuscated all useful clues about your schema by using generic names. The short answer is eitherr you data is flawed (not likely) or your query is logically flawed in some manner (most likely). You need to take it apart and find out why it produces duplicate rows. I see ROW_NUMBER but not usage of the generated value - maybe that is your problem? Your DATEADD usage is concerning - that is not how you adjust for local / UTC time. Notice the inconsistency in status values - code needs a good review.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.AccountId ...
```

is your quickest solution, to eliminate duplicate rows from the final output (based on all column values being identical).  However, DISTINCT is not always the ideal approach (it's often a large hammer for what might be a small nail), and could impact on performance.  You've obviously got a number of different tables in your query (with alias "T"), and it would take a better understanding of exactly how records occur in those tables to optimise this query better.